# Have any meteoroids been detected before they reached the Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: meteor, near-earth-object, meteoroid

Once a meteoroid starts burning up in the atmosphere, it becomes a visible meteor. Have any meteoroids been detected before they started to burn in the atmosphere? If yes, what is the ballpark estimate for the number of meteoroids detected before they reach Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, are you also counting detections that are found in archived data after the meteor is observed, i.e. "precovery" observations, or only discoveries that allow predictions of future meteors?

Comment: I'm also curious about "precovery" detections. How many of each have there been?

Comment: In 2008 a meteoroid was discovered that was successfully predicted to enter the atmosphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_TC3

Comment: @Giovanni Please work that into an answer. Don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: @JamesK My comment is an example. It doesn't answer all the OPs questions

Comment: [Here is the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_prediction#List_of_successfully_predicted_asteroid_impacts).